# Handling a form purely from Javascript

Tags: html, ajax, forms, submit

I have the following form in a [website](http://www.psycowlogist.com) of mine.

```
      <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" value="" />
        <input type="button" name="talk" value="talk" onClick="askCow(this.form)" />
      </form>
```

Clicking the button does fire an AJAX request that updates the page. Using return does not, however; it simply submits the form using GET, which is not the desired behavior. Using `onsumit="return false;"` or similar disables submission, but this is not the desired behavior.

How can I execute the `askCow` function on an enter press ("form submission") while making sure the form is NOT submitted? Am I a bad person for doing this? The reason I use AJAX is that it lets me omit templating logic on the server side entirely.

Thanks!

Edit: here is the complete page

```
<html>
  <head><title>Psycowlogist</title></head>
  <body>
    <div id="history">
      Previous discussion
    </div>
    <div id="cow">
      <pre>
 _______________________
< What is your problem? >
 -----------------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
      </pre>
    </div>
    <div id="talk">
      <form id="talkForm" action="" method="GET" onsubmit="askCow(this)">
        <input type="text" name="query" value="" />
        <input type="button" name="talk" value="talk" onClick="askCow(this.form)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/coffeescript">
    $j = jQuery

    window.askCow = (form) ->
      $j.get "/cowanswer",
      {q: form.query.value},
      (data) -> $j("#cow pre").html(data["cow-answer"])
      return false
  </script>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `onsubmit event` of `form`

```
  <form action="" method="GET" onsubmit="return askCow(this);">
    <input type="text" name="query" value="" />
    <input type="button" name="talk" value="talk"/>
  </form>
```

`askCow` function should look something like this

```
function askCow()
{
    //do ajax stuff
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but the form does get submitted, which resets the page (I also tried `askCow(this) && false`)

Comment: @Rom1 Use the jQuery Form plugin if you want to process it using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) .

And within the call, you can call `askCow()` .

```
    var options = {
        target:        '#output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,  // pre-submit callback 
        success:       showResponse  // post-submit callback 
    }; 

 $('#theForm').submit(function() { 
        askCow(this);
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 

        return false; 
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! I went with the onSubmit solution as it was simpler, but I will keep an eye on this plugin.